# How do I create simple code to select 5 names from input?

Tags: php, jquery

I want create simple puzzle to select random 5 names from input.

Lets say I want to give a gift for my blog commentators. So I collect their name and paste into `textarea`

What I have done for now only form at http://jsfiddle.net/CDSuN/

```
$winner = 'john, micheal, peter, sally, rooney, owen, tevez, ronaldo, wayne rooney, nani';
```

How can be done to select the winners with php or jquery. Let me know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

first put all input text into an array using [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and then choose random value with [array_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)

#### TRIAL

```
$winArray=explode(",",$winner);
$finalWinner= array_rand($winArray,5)
echo "<pre>";
print_r($finalWinner); // return keys
echo "</pre>";

//to retrieve the  name of winners 

for($i=0; $i<5; $i++)
{
    echo $winArray[$i]."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Nice.. how do I return a name instead of `Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 4 [2] => 5 [3] => 7 [4] => 8 )`

Comment: `$winArray[$i]` is not generate random names.

Comment: ok i got it work `foreach ($finalWinner as $key => $value) { echo "<br />".$winArray[$value]; }`

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 2):

php:

```
$namesString = 'john, micheal, peter, sally, rooney, owen, tevez, ronaldo, wayne rooney, nani';

$namesArray = explode(",",$namesString);

$randomIndex = rand(0,sizeof($namesArray));

$winner = $namesArray[$randomIndex];
```

pure javascript:

```
// names is a textarea... like <textarea id='names'>'john, micheal, peter, sally, rooney, owen, tevez, ronaldo, wayne rooney, nani'</textarea>
var namesString = document.getElementById('names').value;
var namesArray = namesString.split(',');

var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*namesArray.length+1)
window.alert("The winner is : "+ namesArray[randomIndex]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a jQuery / javascript way allowing you to change how many numbers are picked if you wanted:

```
$('input.button').click(function() {
    var names = $('#winner').val().split(', ');
    var winnersNums = randomNumbers(5, names.length);
    var winningDiv = $('#theWinners'); 
    var winners = '';
    $.each(winnersNums, function(key, value) {
        winners += names[value]+', ';
    });
    winningDiv.html(winners);
});

function randomNumbers(req, total) {
    var nums = [];
    while (nums.length < req) {
        var temp = Math.floor(Math.random() * (total));
        if (!nums.inArray(temp)) {
            nums.push(temp);
        }
    }
    return nums;
}

Array.prototype.inArray = function(value) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (this[i] == value) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Added to your [**demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/CDSuN/7/)

*And with comments [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/CDSuN/6/)*